# jQuery - show only one item of the same class after click

Tags: jquery

I've got 2 classes - .item and .item-description. Item is always visible but item-description is not. It should be visible right after the user clicks on the button and on the next click it should hide again.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/1/).

The jQuery function looks like this and somehow it is not working :-)

```
$(function() {
  $("table .item td:last-child").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().closest(".item-description").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/4/

Answer (score 3):

You have used wrong selector. you need to either use `.next()` or `.siblings()` instead of `.closest()` :

```
$(this).parent().next().show();
```

using .toggle:

```
$(this).parent().next().toggle();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/2/)**

using toggleClass:

```
$(this).parent().next().toggleClass('item-description');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/5/)**

Comment: FYI (OP), this toggles showing and hiding the div, not the class.  `.toggleClass()` would work for that.

Comment: Does not make any difference. it does the same stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/5/

Comment: I agree with you.  Added that just in case he wanted to toggle between classes with styles other than just `display`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would tackle this problem:

```
$(function () {
    $("table .item td:last-child").click(function () {
        //-- Store a reference to the description element
        var $next = $(this).parent().next('.item-description');
        //-- Toggle the description, causing it to either hide or show.
        $next.toggle();
        //-- hide all sibling descriptions
        $next.siblings('.item-description').hide();
    });
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/8/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
$("table > tbody > tr.item").click(function() {    
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sZp3C/7/**